# Colocar estilo num input[type=checkbox] contendo só parte do id do input

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, scss

Eu tenho um estilo em CSS assim:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    box-shadow:none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Queria colocar num `checkbox` que tem um `id` específio:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='check_" + @bancoDeQuestao.Id + "'></td>
```

Só que esse `id='check_'` varia pois depende de um código que é o `bancoDeQuestao.Id` que vem do banco (é uma lista de checks): `check_23`, `check_24`, etc, os números sempre variam.

Como colocar nesse estilo que ele só considere os inputs que **contenham** o id `check_`?

Comment: Não seria apenas os inputs checkados? Isso não bastaria para solucionar seu problema?

Comment: não são só os 'checados', seriam todos que tiverem parte desse id